# Line output as variable command awk nmap

Tags: python, linux, awk, python-requests, nmap

i trying to find all devices in my network with nmap and send to requests python on port 80 if this is open parsing ip address just like here.

```
rang = "192.168.0.1/24"
ip = os.system("sudo nmap -Pn %s -p80 --open | awk '/is up/ {print up}; {gsub 
(/\(|\)/,\"\"); up = $NF; NR==1}'" %(rang))
r = requests.get("http://%s"%(ip))
```

i want to take the line output as variable and after send a request.
i think that output is ip to ip, but not.

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.6
192.168.0.12
192.168.0.18`
....
```

show all ip's and not send request.

Comment: print r.status_code, r.text
?

Comment: i want to write the banner grabbing into file.